# Inject a parameter before build by EnvInject plugin?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a parameterized build with parameter `VERSION` which has default value `origin/master`.

`VERSION` parameter itself has a value:

```
"${gitlabBranch ?: 'origin/master'}
```

What's mean take `gitlabBranch` if it exist, otherwise use `origin/master`. But in very early build step `gitlabBranch` is not visible by Jenkins, that is why I see values from previous build. For example if previous branch triggered called `A`, but now triggered branch `B`, in `VERSION` parameter of this last build will be value `A`, from previous build.

I need a way specify in very early stage value for `VERSION` variable from `gitlabBranch` var, and GitLab plugin suggest use `EnvInject plugin` for this [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#parameter-configuration). I did simple steps described here but still see the same behaviour - values of `VERSION` take not current value of gitlabBranch.

How it possible put in `VERSION` value coming from current Gitlab hook request?

Comment: you can try to use **parametrized build** and pass branch name as a parameter: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/wiki/Parametrized-pipelines

Comment: Oh man, it's all known. And I already define parameter, as said above VERSION. But when you will pass the value to this param when build it manually? Before build start, correct. But what if my build run also by GitLab hooks (automatically)? And in this gitlab hook is a parameter, which can be accessiable in Pipeline during runtime - $gitlabBranch. And I want put value of this parameter into my VERSION parameter BEFORE build can start even. Seems it's possible by EnvInject plugin but not for me...